# htaccess redirecting one query string to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**I'd like to redirect** `http://domain.com/videos/?src=category1&video=video1`

**To** `http://domain.com/videos/watch?v=1`

The obvious, just using a `Redirect 301 /old /new` doesn't work here. Here's my starting point and I can't seem to get this to redirect properly. This .htaccess file lives in the videos directory.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=category1&video=video1$ [NC]
RewriteRule /videos/watch\?v=1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you share your attempted rule?

Comment: I added some code that i've been working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=category1&video=video1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /videos/watch?v=1 [L,R=301]
```

You were missing the rewrite rule's regex pattern.

Comment: ah makes sense, still not working though - i'm not getting any errors. It's just not doing anything.

Comment: @Dan is the htaccess file in your document root? or in a directory called "video"?

Comment: It's in the video directory. Ah so must be a path issue?

Comment: @Dan yeah, the place the htaccess file is at determines what URI gets put through the rules, so we need to remove `video` from the pattern because that bit is stripped off.

Comment: Actually the RewriteRule should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /videos/watch?v=1 [R=301,L]` or it will not work.